# Understanding Skiena's description of "Hashing and Strings"

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, hashtable, string-hashing

In the "Algorithm Design Manual" book by Skiena the following paragraph is present in page 80 under heading **3.7 Hashing and Strings**

> Let α be the size of the alphabet on which a given string S is
>   written. Let char(c) be a function that maps each symbol of the
>   alphabet to a unique integer from 0 to α − 1.

What does the "size of alphabet" mean in the above paragraph? Don't all the alphabets (a-z) have the same size? Also how is it possible to write the string S on the alphabet α. Aren't alphabets put together to form a string?

Answer (score 4):

The size α of the alphabet is meant to be the total number of symbol which can be used for the string S. Depending on the situation, alphabets may vary. For instance, binary numbers can be represented using the alphabet `{0,1}` (α=2), one can use the Latin lowecase letters `{a,...,z}` (α=26) or symbols for representing numbers in hexadecimal using `{0,...,9,A,...,F}` (α=16).

Comment: It should have been written as range instead of size. It confused me too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confused as to what "alphabet" means. An alphabet is not a single symbol, but a set of all possible symbols that might appear in the string. The English alphabet has 26 symbols. The Hebrew alphabet has 22 symbols (and they're different symbols than the English alphabet).

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling myself to understand that hashing function until I found an example of its usage. What Skiena is describing there is a variant of Rabin-Karp string searching algorithm as described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

The hashing function used is the following:

> Let `α` be the size of the alphabet on which a given string `S` is
>   written. Let `char(c)` be a function that maps each symbol of the
>   alphabet to a unique integer from `0` to `α − 1`:
>
> [image: enter image> description here]

The size α of the alphabet is the number of symbols which can be used to represent the string S.

From the Wikipedia page linked above:

> The Rabin fingerprint treats every substring as a number in some base,
>   the base being usually a large prime. For example, if the substring is
>   `"hi"` and the base is `101`, the hash value would be:

```
104 * 101^1 + 105 * 101^0 = 10609 // (ASCII of 'h' is 104 and of 'i' is 105).
```

Note that Skiena is defining the `char()` function as a mapping from a symbol of the alphabet to an integer from `0` to `α − 1`, while on Wikipedia example the digit code can actually be larger than the alphabet size, anyway this should give you an idea of how to apply the formula.